# Count items in datasource or inside repeater

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, repeater, sqldatasource, asprepeater

I found some other questions about this argument but I can't get anything to work.
I have a repeater with datasource, this is my repeater code:

```
<div class="container dafareoggi" id="divDaFareOggi">
    <div runat="server" id="divSegnaposto"></div>
    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptDaFareOggi" DataSourceID="SqlAttivitaDaFareOggi">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div id="<%# Eval("id") %>">
                <div class="div-titolo" title="<%# Eval("Titolo") %>"><%# Eval("Titolo") %></div>
                <div class="div-testo" title="<%# Eval("Note") %>"><%# Eval("Note") %></div>
                <div>
                    <table style="width: 100%;margin-top:0.5em;padding-right:0.2em;">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width: 50%; text-align: left;">
                                <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/gabri.png" Width="2.3em" Height="2.3em" ToolTip='<%#Eval("tecnico")%>' Enabled="false" Visible='<%# IIf(Eval("idutente") = 8, True, False) %>'/>
                                <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/giuse.png" Width="2.3em" Height="2.3em" ToolTip='<%#Eval("tecnico")%>' Enabled="false" Visible='<%# IIf(Eval("idutente") = 2, True, False) %>'/>
                                <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/robi.png" Width="2.3em" Height="2.3em" ToolTip='<%#Eval("tecnico")%>' Enabled="false" Visible='<%# IIf(Eval("idutente") = 5, True, False) %>'/>
                            </td>
                            <td style="width: 50%; text-align: right; ">
                                <asp:LinkButton CommandName="delAttivita" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ID")%>' runat="server" ID="lnkDelAtt" CausesValidation="False" OnClientClick="return confirm('Sei sicuro di voler eliminare questa attivita?');"><i class="fa fa-trash fa-lg" title="Elimina attività"></i></asp:LinkButton>
                                <asp:LinkButton CommandName="editAttivita" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ID")%>' runat="server" ID="lnkEditAtt"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square fa-lg" title="Modifica attività"></i></asp:LinkButton>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</div>
```

In the repeater there is a place card div with id `divSegnaposto` (2nd row) and then a bunch of div **may** be loaded accordingly to data read from the db.
What I want is that when there are no data to load, so `divSegnaposto` is the only item, to show it and, vice versa, when there are 1 ore more other divs, to hide it.

I figure that I should count the number of items inside the repeater or rows inside datasouce (I'm using EF), so I tried different approach in `repeater_databound_event`, but for example `repeater.items.count` is always 0.

How can I achieve the goal?

Comment: `divSegnaposto` is not inside repeater.

Comment: yeah, forget about it, it was just to explain the final goal. But how can I count divs inside repeater?

Comment: show your `repeater_databound` event

Comment: I tried with rptDaFareOggi.items.count but, like I said, is always 0

Comment: did you converted your repeater in event?

Comment: Personally- I'd simply put the data into a collection and then add that collection as a datasource. Then you can get your count from the collection and then decide whether or not to show stuff.

Comment: I ended up using a linq query that gets the same as the sqldatasource at itembound event and then I check if it's empty or not and show\hide the placecard accordingly. I don't like it too much because makes me mad: I already have all the information I need inside the repeater or the sql data source, so I guess I thought there was an easier, less code-consuming way to do it. But all the answers I found are more complicated than just re-do the query in code behind...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a linq query that gets the same as the sqldatasource at itembound event and then I check if it's empty or not and show\hide the placecard accordingly. I don't like it too much because makes me mad: I already have all the information I need inside the repeater or the sql data source, so I guess I thought there was an easier, less code-consuming way to do it. But all the answers I found are more complicated than just re-do the query in code behind...